# If let condition true when value is missing in optional type, swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have parser in Objc, parser returns NSDictionary. I am using this parser in swift class. But when some value is missing on that dictionary, it shows nil value. e.g. ->

```
wirlessData = {
   "anon" = {     
   };
   "channel" = {
       "text" = 1;
   };
}
```

I am checking through

```
if let wepauthValue = wirlessData["wepauth"] {

   if let value = wepauthValue["text"] {

       print("\(value)")  // nil
   }
}
```

I don't how it satisfy the if let condition. Any one faced this types of problem can help me out.

Thanks,
vikash

[image]

Comment: can you make a complete snippet to reproduce in Playground?

Comment: If you alt (or option) click on `anonValue`, what does it say?

Comment: How does the compiler know that `anonValue` is also a dictionary (and can use subscript operator)?

Comment: @HennyLee, its shows 
anonValue: XCUIELement

Comment: @ EI Captain, anonValue is just any example, use 'wepauth' instead of anonValue.

Comment: @EICaptain, yes, if the value or key is not present . it should break the flow.But it is not happening now.

Comment: I tried ... it doesn't print nil and same in your snap ... it just step over from loop where does it printed

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any special code to do this, because it is what a dictionary already does. When you fetch dict[key] you know whether the dictionary contains the key, because the Optional that you get back is not nil (and it contains the value).

So, if you just want to answer the question whether the dictionary contains the key, ask:

```
let keyExists = dict[key] != nil
```

If you want the value and you know the dictionary contains the key, say:

```
let val = dict[key]!
```

But if, as usually happens, you don't know it contains the key - you want to fetch it and use it, but only if it exists - then use something like if let:

```
if let val = dict[key] {
// now val is not nil and the Optional has been unwrapped, so use it
}
```

Comment: So why does it print "nil" inside of the `if` ?

Comment: nil here means that there is no key exists with same name

Comment: you say "now val is not nil and the Optional has been unwrapped, so use it". So how can val print "nil"?

Comment: added screen shots, have a look

Answer (score 0):

The value your parser is returning not nil, its empty so you need to check on count if inner data type is dictionary or array, I have past 1 sample here

Please use below code and correct your logic accordingly to get it work properly

```
let wirlessData:[String:AnyObject] = [
    "anon" : [],

    "channel" :  [
        "text" : 1
        ]
    ]
    if wirlessData["anon"]?.count > 0 {

        if let value = wirlessData["anon"]!["text"] {

            print("\(value)")  // nil
        }
    }
```

Comment: Updated the answer please check and let me know if your problem still not resolved :)

Comment: Boss, i am getting  wireless data from my parser, i can't change that syntax . that why i told you to read question. it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: added screen shots, have a look

Comment: OK it means the field is empty but still you are entering into if condition ? is it so?

Comment: Done please check updated code, the snapshot you attached in that the value is not nil its empty so you need to check on count

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it and found that `value` is still optional.Take a look at screenshot below to understand it better.
[image]

Comment: i added screen shots, have a look

Answer (score 0):

"anon" would be an empty dictionary. An empty dictionary is not nil, it is a dictionary. Just an empty one. A JSON parser will never, ever give nil values unless you ask for a key that is not in a dictionary. For example wirlessData ["nonexistingkey"] would give you nil.

Comment: added screen shots, have a look

Answer (score 0):

If you be more type-strong about it with the if..let's then:

```
if let anonValue = wirlessData["anon"] {

   if let value = anonValue["text"] as? String {
       // This won't execute if value isn't converted from `anonvalue["text"]` to String specifically. This includes null been a false match too
       print("\(value)")  // nil
   }else{
       print("Value did't match string at all")
   }
}
```

or even more specifically in your case:

```
if let anonValue = wirlessData["anon"] {

   if let value = anonValue["text"] as? Int {
       // This won't execute if value isn't converted from `anonvalue["text"]` to String specifically. This includes null been a false match too
       print("\(value)")  // nil
   }else{
       print("Value did't match int at all")
   }
}
```

Comment: added screen shots, have a look

Comment: Do you mean if the value "1" = Boolean "true" and value "0" = boolean false? In that case, case it to NSNumber as Obj-C boolean equates to NSNumber 1 / 0

Comment: Anyway, if you cast to Bool directly (if the above is the case) it should case directly.. i.e. `if let myValue = UnknownBool as? Bool ....`

Comment: it is string value, i don't any bool or int value. i only want string value

Comment: AH WAIT! I just noticed.... Look closely at your debugger... Some of the text is enclosed in "" i.e. in the password result, you see text : `"`123`"` (hence the quotes)... Is it possible that other values returned under "text" ain't always returned as string (or NSString)?

Comment: I'm still puzzled as to why some of the debug info has quotes around it and some doesn't... Have you tried casting from NSString i.e. `value as? NSString`

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code using [type check](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html) operator `(is)` -

```
if wirlessData["anon"] is [String:AnyObject]
{
    let anon = wirlessData["anon"]!
    print(anon)

    if anon["random"] is String {
        let stringValue = anon["random"]!
        print("\(stringValue)")
    }
    else if anon["random"] is Int
    {
        let intValue = anon["random"]!
        print("\(intValue)")  // nil
    }
    else
    {
        print(" may be value did't match string & Int or nil ")
    }
}
```